# How to do a transparent compression of a folder on Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint?

Tags: compression

Its known, its possible to compress complete file systems by useing p.e. btrfs. Also known it`s possible to compress p.e. Ext4 and some other file systems inside a .qcow2 useing VM. See follow:

[How to enable transparent drive compression for Ext4 partition used by Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/635016/how-to-enable-transparent-drive-compression-for-ext4-partition-used-by-debian-u/720320#720320)

How to do only a transparent compression on Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint on a folder like the follow ?

```
/home/user/my_folder
```

Comment: This are different questions.

Comment: @Alfred.37 If it's a different question, then why is your answer to that question _identical_ to one of your answers to _this_ question?  Is your answer to that question in fact not an answer and should be deleted?